# Why are there "beginner" and "advanced" English sites on the SE network, but not for programming?

Tags: discussion, split-stack-overflow

There are two English language sites in the SE network:

- [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)
- [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com)

These are two different sites with different foci. I'm afraid I am not familiar with the history of these two sites and how they each came into being (and I see that ELL is still in the beta phase of site creation).

What makes English language questions different from programming, such that the distinction between ELL and ELU can be justified, while such a split is not tenable for Stack Overflow? A commonly cited reason for *not* splitting SO is "people want to ask questions on the site where all the experts are". Why doesn't that apply to ELL/ELU?

Comment: A more interesting parallel would be MathOverflow / Math.SE.

Comment: Or: [stats.SE] and [datascience.SE]. Maybe a bit less: [cs.SE] and [cstheory.SE]

Comment: Isn't Code Review more a beginners' site?

Comment: @MrLister Code Review is for people who already have the code and want it improved.

Comment: Why *should* there be beginner and advanced sites for programming? I'm not seeing any compelling reason, or really any reason at all, in your question.

Comment: ELL is not for beginners in *speaking*, but for beginners in speaking English.

Comment: @Kaz: I think that's a _really_ important point that would be good to have in an answer. Would you care to flesh it out?

Comment: i like the idea however i would say that why split it up beginners should be learning the advanced programming methods from the start or it will just slow them down to learn this way as a learner and then get told that it's no good for memory or CPU and have to learn a new way thats more complicated to understand but a lot better for memory like using `fseek` in php compared to loading the whole file using `fread` and then getting php to do it's methods

Answer (score 33):

ELL and ELU have *each* sprouted up from proposals of sites on Area 51. These were separate proposals with specific different foci. The different foci were in the audience - people *learning* English vs. people conversant in English, but wishing to discuss topics more subtle than beginners would be comfortable with.

Stack Overflow has very different beginnings - no grass roots proposals with limited foci. The focus it currently has came organically - the site and the community grew side-by-side (which you well know as someone who was there in the beta trenches).

And yet, there are several sites that are focused on different/sub aspects of programming on the network, most of which also came through from proposals on Area 51 - Programmers, Game Development, and a bunch of CMS-related sites (WordPress, CMS, and a few more).

So, there is such a differentiation already in place. I invite you to take a look at the Programmers [help center on-topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and contrast it to the [Stack Overflow on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

The foci, though both are programming Q&A sites, are different.

So, in my eyes, saying that:

> such a split is not tenable for Stack Overflow

Is not accurate. There **is** such a split (call it focus on audience/sub-topic) already in place.

Consider, as well, our [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) - a site dedicated to programming as well, albeit in a different human language - how is this any different? And I can assure you that we have heard concerns from the community that this kind of site will split/break up what Stack Overflow is.

Comment: I changed "split" when referring to ELL/ELU above to "distinction", so that I wasn't implying that they were one site that split into two.

Comment: For the sub aspects, the distinction is between goals, not expertise of the askers while that is the main distinction between ELL and ELU. Why shouldn't there be a SOForDummies?

Comment: Because blind leading the blind is not something we're interested in encouraging, @Jonathan. ELL is **not** "English for Dummies" - and by the same token, a site focused on *teaching* programming might have some legs, as long as it avoided falling into this "let's make a ghetto for SO" trap.

Comment: @Shog9 Have you seen the front page?  SO is its own ghetto...

Comment: Who uses the front page? Tag filters are where it's at, @Izkata.

Comment: @pnuts - pt.so is a site about programming, in the same vein of Stack Overflow, my point there being - there idea that [so] is monolithic (one site to rule them all, in regards to programming) is false. As for a need - I didn't address that at all. I am saying that we have sites that have grown, grass-roots, to address different audiences. That a "beginner" site never came to be is telling.

Comment: Nice answer. The broad topic of "programming" is already covered by far more Stack Exchange sites than "English" is. And there have been some that feel more like they *were* split off from SO, and others that grew more from scratch alongside SO. (I think of Code Golf and Code Review in the "split off" category; Programmers and the rest in the "grown separately" category.)

Comment: Well, I use the front page.  To shoot my "close all the questions" shotgun at all the questions asked by the new folks who passed on reading the Tour and the Help Center for guidance.

Comment: @pnuts: I don't understand your comment at all. How is it a response to my comment?

Comment: @Shog9 Even if you avoid looking at the ghetto, it is still there. We already lost all the webprogramming tags, as it seems.

Comment: Programmers is - in my eyes - a split of SO, for the questions without code.

Comment: Have you seen ELL, @GregHewgill? There's some amazing expertise there. I am frequently impressed by the quality of answers, and fairly often by the quality of questions.

Answer (score 22):

There are two *distinct* groups of English speakers - those fluent in the language, and those learning it as a second language.

Programmers are always learning, as the state of the industry and our tools are *always* in flux, so it doesn't make sense to have a separate environment for learners vs. professionals.

Comment: I can swear fluently in about 10 programming languages!

Comment: You could just as well argue that there are two distinct groups of programmers - _actual_ programmers (those fluent in _any_ programming language), and people who want to or have to program something but don't actually know what they're doing at all. Surely there's a distinction between someone who programmed C for 20 years and now has to learn python, and someone who just started his first programming course.

Comment: @l4mpi, There are experts that are willing to answer questions on the ELL site.   I expect there will not be for a "no nothing about programming" site.   Just look at the PHP tag!

Comment: I think "goto" is a swear word in all of them.

Comment: @IanRingrose That's always an argument against such a split; but there actually are people who enjoy helping newcomers - as long as the newbie is able to form a coherent sentence, of course (which may not be the case for most of the PHP tag). Anyways, I think the split could happen in the other direction - an Area51 proposal for a site for _professional_ programmers. No "enthusiasts" anymore, explicitly disallow beginners. A site for seriously hard questions only. I feel we need something like this, as the harder questions are buried by a heap of easy crap on SO...

Comment: I would welcome a "beginners" site precisely because I like to help people who want to learn, and would like to be able to do so without seeing them being hassled for not already knowing what they are trying to learn.

Comment: @David And "Java" for most.

Comment: The problem with implementing a "beginners" site is getting "beginners" to use it. I feel it would be far more productive to go in the other direction, making a site for "professionals" by "professionals". The difficulty comes in though when you try to decide what kind of questions go where. All of the questions that get asked on the new "Professional" site would be applicable to the non-professional site, and only a *very* small subset of the questions on the non-professional site wouldn't be appilcable on the professional site, unless the rules are far more strict than they already are.

Comment: I think a lot of high rep users wouldn't care that they are no longer high rep, it's the loss of moderation power in their favorite tags that would likely be  more of an issue. I would hate to have to work back up to 20k and work back up to a gold badge in javascript to get all of the benefits i have now. I could care less if my rep dropped 35k points.

Comment: Realistically it would probably be more suitable in this case to have the rep shared.

Comment: Exactly, that's part of the challenge we would have to sort out before making this kind of change. Just because a user is new to SO and doesn't quite understand the requirements doesn't mean they aren't an expert in their field. That would make separating questions between the two sites very difficult. I don't think a split based on "advanced" vs "beginner" would actually solve anything. If anything the split should be community based and not skill/quality based.

Answer (score 19):

Your assumption is mistaken.  These are not 'beginner' and 'advanced' sites.  They are sites for very different subjects which have similar labels.  Their experts are also different.

All you need to do is look at their descriptions.

***English Language Learners***

This site is for "speakers of other languages learning English"

As such, its experts are those who not only speak the English Language, but preferably, also speak the language that the one asking the question is coming from.  The experts are those who are used to teaching English to those who do not speak it, from a classroom or course attitude.

***English Language & Usage***

This site is for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts"

As such, its experts are, yes, those who speak English, but also those who focus on English.  The experts for this are not necessarily teachers of any stripe, nor do they have to understand the way English differs from other languages (though often they do.)  They need to understand history of words.  Where words come from, how they developed, very *specific* definitions.

For instance:  take the words 'Morals and Ethics'.

For "English Language Learners" this would be the proper response if someone asked the difference between Morals and Ethics:

```
The two terms mean mostly the same thing, but with a connotation that morals 
are imposed upon others, while ethics are an internal decision on right and 
wrong.
```

While "English Language and Usage" would have this as a proper response:

```
While common usage tends to go the opposite way, the technical difference 
between Morals and Ethics is in Morals being an internal and informal 
understanding of Right and Wrong, while Ethics are a set of frameworks put 
in place, usually by a group or institution, laying out the proper and 
improper activities, or 'right and wrong' acts.  While technically an 
institution can help influence a person's individual moral guide, and may 
tell someone what their moral guide should be, an institution can only 
institute a code of ethics.

(insert history of the word 'morals')

(insert history of the word 'ethics') 

(insert reference links here)
```

NOTE:  these definitions of morals and ethics may or may not be right, but this is meant merely as a demonstration of how a correct answer can be very different for the two sites.

It's understandable that these could be confused for 'beginners' and 'experts', but ... and this is just my opinion - I find that the ELU answer would confuse more than clarify for an ELL question.  Especially because ... since ELL is for foreign learners of the language ... the language used for the ELU answer is, by necessity, going to be more complex English.

Comment: @pnuts  I'm afraid I'm not sure what SU stands for... ?  But I was speaking very specifically that there are very different 'right' answers for ELL and ELU that are NOT 'beginner' and 'expert' answers, but instead the difference is closer to why there would be a different stack site for 'Current Events' than for 'History'.

Comment: I like the way you put that last sentence.

Comment: While most of your post I agree with, the second sentence is incorrect; they *are* beginner and advanced sites, as your post clearly illustrates :-) Though personally I feel ELU should be renamed to English Thesaurus and History, based on its use.

Comment: I agree with what I think you're saying here -- that the premise of this question is mistaken -- but I don't think that your example illustrates that same thing. The two samples you gave really read as the "beginner" and "advanced" versions of the same answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm not sure how when the answers are exactly opposite each other...

Answer (score 4):

Comparing English Language Learners and English Language & Usage to beginner and advanced sites, respectively, doesn't quite make sense.

I don't think English teachers (or people willing to teach English) would feel deterred from using ELL. On the contrary, ELL would also be designed for them.

In addition, where there is overlap between ELL and ELU, my guess is that you don't need the same degree of expertise (not necessarily experience, but main speciality) to spot that there is something wrong with an answer. By this, I mean if there's a difficult question that would require input from an "advanced" user<sup>(*)</sup>, but instead gets an incorrect answer from a "beginner", an intermediate user (not necessarily specialist or linguist) would probably be able to spot that something isn't quite right with such an answer.

That's not necessarily the case for programming. There are questions, even by beginners, that require a relatively good degree of expertise in the field, from the start (at the very least to approve or disapprove with existing answers).

I remember seeing a case like this on SO a while back. I can't remember the exact question, but it was about encrypting/hashing passwords in PHP. Within 2 minutes, non-experts were pasting snippets of code to try to answer the question (in a FGITW way), producing answers that had the appearance to be correct and helpful (they got rid of the problem and produced what looked like an "encrypted result", i.e. gibberish). A few minutes later, someone more expert in crypto (and with the relevant knowledge of the PHP API) produced a detailed answer, not only giving a correct solution, but explaining what was wrong with the other answers, and why they were insecure.

I guess it's quite clear that if we split SO into beginner and advanced, experts would probably not be much present on the beginner's site. Hence, wrong ideas would self-perpetuate on the beginner's site.

I don't quite see the same sort of use case happening on ELL, simply because ELL is not just for beginners but also for experts, focussed on a different objective.

<sub>(*) Here, I'm making the assumption that ELL is for beginners and ELU is advanced users, although I think this assumption is flawed.</sub>

Comment: @pnuts The fact that a question is also on topic on Security.SE doesn't make it invalid here. In fact, a number of programming questions can have a security angle, many can also received answers with security flaws (let's just try to count how many PHP+MySQL answers we'll see with a SQL injection vulnerability), without necessarily being valid on Security.SE. Security.SE is generally not so much focussed purely on the programming side either.

Comment: @pnuts I don't think things are deteriorating nearly as rapidly as some perceive it. Rather, there's a relatively small core of usual users ("experts" if you wish) who have been contributing for a while. Firstly, they might just get fed up with all this, that's life (also possibly running out of knowledge to spread, at least learning not as fast as the demand for answer comes in). Secondly, a small increase in new users might also turn out to make the workload go above the acceptable levels that the core answerers can handle.

Comment: @pnuts I would certainly say a number of "expert" answerers are not necessarily that interested in Meta indeed. I've only been active here quite recently. Bizarrely, what seems to drive me here tends to be the perception that rules are becoming more stringent, and questions unnecessarily closed. I've always been mainly active on a relatively low traffic tag, and you tend to see a number of regular users there. Until a few weeks/months ago, getting someone to close a bad question was difficult, you had 2 or 3 close votes, but you rarely got to the 5 required, probably by lack of viewers. (cont)

Comment: (...cont...). Now, I've seen questions that were not necessarily great, but that I'd call "fair" questions being closed by people who'd never participated in any way on this tag. For example, "*I don't really know what I'm going, but I'm trying to achieve X, I've tried this, and it produced error Y, ...*": a question with good intent, a reasonably problem, which may need a little bit of additional details via comments, but something answerable and useful. More annoyingly for everyone, they're often closed with reasons that have nothing to do with their actual shortcomings (e.g. "unclear").

Comment: @pnuts It's hard to know how SO was meant to be. Although it was possibly always meant to be a repository of good, curated knowledge (as a noble goal), it was never really built for that completely. It was built as a Q&A site: "*Ask questions, get answers, no distractions*". Authorship and rep have also always been at the core of the system, with very little to encourage *actual* collaboration towards building a set of coherent Q&A documents together. In fact, everything was done *not* to build communities, which could have encouraged more collaborative work, despite other potential problems.

Comment: @pnuts The advantage of gathering knowledge in a Q&A site compared to something more encyclopaedic (like Wikipedia for example) is that you can tailor the knowledge in the answer to the question, using the vocabulary used in the question for anyone who would search using these words (which might not be the words used by the experts, but the words typically used by people having that problem). Hunting for duplicates and closing them to pointing to "canonical question" actually hinders that aspect unfortunately. SO has a number of goals and mechanisms that somehow seem to contradict each other.

Answer (score 2):

Many questions on SO are not about theory and not about best practice but requests for quick fixes. Splitting SO seems unlikely to stop the deluge of questions overall since for most people any answer, other than a plain wrong one, is better than none – and in any case does not have to be applied.

For these, "people want to ask questions on the site where all the experts are" does not convince me, though a valid consideration. The system in place is very effective in ensuring answers are generally good quality but many times the green tick is not against what I would deem the best answer. In the niche I frequent speed seems to count more than quality does, given answers of a similar standard.

MetaSO already has very many mentions of (a) a decline in the quality of questions (b) lack of friendliness to newcomers and (c) experts being driven away (or the threat thereof) – with the incidence of each appearing to be on the increase.

(a) Seems inevitable due to increased popularity (the enthusiasts who grew the site are becoming outnumbered by the occasional visitors with quite different priorities) and, to a degree that I think is not fully offset by developments, because the (interesting/challenging) fundamentals have mostly been covered (in many cases, hundreds of times).
(b) The number of questions that at some point mention “be gentle, I’m a noob” or similar, and comments in chat and meta posts would indicate, to me, that many newcomers do feel concerned about snide comments etc.
(c) Some high profile experts have been driven away and, as far as I can tell, many others either reduced their participation or are becoming inclined to.
Splitting SO along the lines of programming language has not been suggested, I think for good reason, but along the lines of Advanced v. Intermediate/Beginner is well worth consideration, IMO. There would be new problems but it has the potential to mitigate many of the current ones, with the trade-off not obvious to me. Smaller sites seem to be more effective in identifying duplicates (with themselves).

I take Software Recommendations as a kind of precedent. Less than 6 months in public beta at present and of the five key performance indicators already three are OK and one Excellent. The answered percentage is 60% (90% is deemed healthy) but given the topic may not be as strong a disincentive to visitors as on other sites. Also, SO in Portuguese (4 Excellent, 1 OK after barely more than 6 months). Neither is full-blown yet but they are ‘looking good’ despite the concerns expressed at the proposal stage - some of which (eg dilution of expertise) also apply to an SO split.

SO’s size inevitably degrades the community spirit that existed in its first few years. Hiving parts off, on whatever basis, has the potential to return towards a ‘family atmosphere’. Separate out ‘Intermediate’ and, hopefully, the experts would remain titillated by challenging issues without being bothered with many “yet another trivial variation on a topic already flogged to death”. And have time to address more thoroughly the much smaller volume of questions flowing in to SO. SO might revert towards the ‘good old days’ and answers move towards the elusive goal of “canonical”. But some departure of experts is just the ‘natural flow’. Novelty wears off, for example.

Beginners should not feel as intimidated on their own site as they sometimes do on a site that, at times, may appear to tolerate them with reluctance. Perhaps ease up *a little* on the current near mandatory requirement to post code if to stand much chance of a response other than some variation on “What have you tried?” I recognise that objective assessment of the quality of answers on any ‘Intermediate’ site is very likely to be less than on an (Advanced) SO. But it seems the requirement is *often* not the best answer but mostly something that will “tide me over immediately” and, to a lesser extent, “better something I am vaguely familiar with than the theoretical but obscure best solution”.

There should be little to fear from a shortage of expertise on an ‘Intermediate’ site. There *are* people who just want to help and others will ‘pay it forward’. Beginners helping beginners can be more effective at times than experts who are so precise their jargon is incomprehensible to the general public. SO already co-exists effectively with SU and Web Applications etc , despite considerable overlap of coverage for some tags.

In other fields a split might be termed ‘market segmentation’. SE needs to generate revenue, which greater focus can increase.

“That does not apply to ELL/ELU” for the same reasons as it, probably, does not apply to SO.