# May I ask for tips?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

I have a piece of JavaScript code I want to ask advice on. I want to know if I may post a question on the main site, asking for tips on a piece of code I have written. I don't want the answer, just tips. May I do this?

I wrote the code myself, but I am unable to proceed. I would just like some advice on how to proceed - like "use a function" or whatever. Or is there a beginner's site to ask questions?

Comment: You should try https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TravisJ:  No.  Just...no.

Comment: @TravisJ:  We don't know if the code works.  We don't know how far along they are in writing the code.  We don't know if the code is being used in something that's readily reviewable.  We don't know if the code is *suitable* to be reviewed.  It could be that the OP is *just* looking for advice on what they do "next".  I'm sorry if my "no" sounded curt, but that is simply frustration and exasperation boiling over at this point from people *willfuly* suggesting the wrong thing.

Comment: @Makoto - Sounds to me like you are simply assuming the worst.

Comment: By far the best site recommendation is none whatsoever.  Suggesting a site for some issue you have not even seen is asking for it come back and bite you in the a. . aftermath.

Comment: @TravisJ:  Do me a personal favor and *peruse* [Code Review's own guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/9874) on when to and when *not* to suggest Code Review to posters on Stack Overflow.  You're quite literally doing what they *don't* want you to do.

Comment: @Makoto - In the instance where there is no code, or the code does not execute, sure. In the instance where this user has a piece of working code and would like to have it reviewed, I disagree. To note, *you don't know that*, and suggesting that this user simply not do anything assumes the worst of what they have written.

Comment: @TravisJ:  The reason I'm suggesting they not is precisely *because* we don't know.  Without code, we can't empirically say if this would be suitable for Code Review or not, and y'know, they actually cover that in their guide.  Tell you what - I'm going to disengage from this conversation since it's not fruitful at this point.

Comment: @TravisJ They've indicated that they *don't* have a finished product, so we *know* that CR isn't appropriate.  So you *are* suggesting a completely inappropriate site for this situation.  If it *were* actually ambiguous, and we didn't know (even though we do know) whether or not the OP had a finished solution or not, just suggesting CR as you have would *still* be wrong.  You would, at a minimum, want to clarify when it would or wouldn't be an appropriate site, for example, by indicating, "If you have a finished and working solution [...]," which you did not do.

Comment: see also: [Why are there “beginner” and “advanced” English sites on the SE network, but not for programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266443/839601)

Comment: @Servy - The presumption you are making is with regards to a finished product being required at code review. However, that is not the case, the code just needs to be working (of which there is no indication that isn't the case here - just that it is incomplete). The part of your conclusion based on that false premise is not really applicable. However, I will attempt in the future to state "If you have a working solution" as a preface since I think that is good advice.

Comment: [You may have better luck at Quora](https://www.quora.com/Whats-wrong-with-my-C-code-2) (though, strangely, they are moving [towards Yahoo Answers](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed), having removed *"question details"* i August 2017).

Answer (score 11):

No, that's not appropriate.  SO is for specific problems, not general advice.

Comment: Just as an aside, I explicitly didn't mention Code Review since there's no guarantee that the code is even in a working state, and I'd *really* not like to throw people over that fence anymore if I can help it...

Comment: @Servy It is my own code I wrote and I want to proceed, but I am unsure how and would like advice on it

Comment: @horcrux88 _How do I proceed_ likely is a broad/opinion based question (there are often multiple ways to proceed) that doesn't fit on any of the SE sites

Answer (score 9):

No.  We're really not suited to provide "tips" since that would make your question either too broad (there are *many* tips that can be provided), or opinion-based (my tips are better than others' tips).